# Passing a reference from a div to a component within the same render function

Tags: reactjs

In my code below, I'm trying to pass a ref of div to the Hello component, but I'm not sure how to approach this. Currently Hello is receiving null as ref which makes sense as the ref hasn't being assigned yet.

I believe I can use componentDidMount and states to update Hello, but there's probably a better way?

```
class App extends React.Component {
  private myDiv: HTMLDivElement;
  render() {
    return <div>
      <div ref={(div) => this.myDiv = div}>Test</div>
      <Hello aDiv={this.myDiv} />  
    </div>;
  }
}

class Hello extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props);
  }

  render() {
    return <div />;
  }
}
```

[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/weyseal/pen/qLaevw)

Updated post with an example using states and using 2 refs instead of 1. It works, but I wish I could access the refs during Hello initialization and not in the componentDidMount. Is there a way to do so?

```
class App extends React.Component {
  private myDiv1: HTMLDivElement;
  private myDiv2: HTMLDivElement;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      myDiv1: null,
      myDiv2: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('App:: componentDidMount');

    this.setState({
      myDiv1: this.myDiv1,
      myDiv2: this.myDiv2
    })
  }

  render() {
    console.log('App:: render');
    return <div>
      <div ref={(div) => this.myDiv1 = div}>div 1</div>
      <div ref={(div) => this.myDiv2 = div}>div 2</div>
      <Hello aDiv1={this.state.myDiv1} aDiv2={this.state.myDiv2} />  
    </div>;
  }
}

class Hello extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('Hello:: componentDidMount');
    console.log(this.props.aDiv1, this.props.aDiv2);
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log('Hello:: componentDidUpdate');
    console.log(this.props.aDiv1, this.props.aDiv2);    
  }

  render() {
    return <div />;
  }
}
```

[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/weyseal/pen/vvyBwZ)

Comment: You can create the ref up-front: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs . This may also be relevant: https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html

Comment: Thanks. I've looked at forwarding refs before, but I thought it was for a component to pass its ref to children which is not the case here. I'll check it again.

Comment: Updated my comment.

Comment: I've created another Codepen with a functional code which does what I want by using states: https://codepen.io/weyseal/pen/vvyBwZ  Note that Hello only gets the refs in the componentDidUpdate call. Is there a way to receive the proper refs during the component initialization?

Comment: I mean, you can create refs up front (as shown in the first link), but it will only have a value once the node was actually rendered.

Comment: Thanks again. I ended up changing the component hierarchy a bit which took care of this ref mess. :)